# On/Off His Routine

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, idioms, figurative-language

I have a question about the usages of "*on*" and "*off*" with "*routine*":

> 1. He was ***on*** his ***routine***.
> 2. He was ***off*** his ***routine***.

The above usages could be found on the web, but not in dictionaries.  So, are the sentences wrong?

Comment: They probably didn't show up in the dictionary because of the pronoun "his", but regardless, just because a phrase doesn't show up in the dictionary, doesn't mean it's necessarily incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any problem in either of them.

That's because 'on' and 'off' are used that way.

So,

> He's on his routine - *sounds okay to me!*

May be, he *then* needed a break from his routine...so...

> He's off his routine!

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct. In #2, you could also say "He was off of his routine."